# free string as a field in a struct

Tags: c++, string

I need to free string object in a field of a struct, wonder how should I do it.

```
struct strDum {
    int a;
    string b;
    strDum(): a(), b() {};
};

//in the code
strDum x;
x.b.append("this is a long string ....");
//do something else
...
//need to free the memory allocated in x.b, how do I do it?
//should I use delete &(x.b)?
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Didn't mention the reason why I need to free the strings: I need to manage  many of the structs like the above, the string field can take lots of memory (each struct  itself doesn't take much memory compared to that of the strings), so I need to free up the memory pointed to by string object whenever possible.

Comment: Why not just [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) the string? And if you are really worried about a few hundred bytes (or a few kilobytes for a *really* long string) then just [shrink the capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) after clearing. I am also very interested in *why* you want to "free" the memory? What is your use-case?

Comment: you probably shouldn't 'delete' memory that you didn't allocate with 'new'.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimPileborg,  :shrink_to_fit() after clear() is the method I am looking forward!! If you turn your comment into a question, I will accept it.

Comment: Have you heard of a destructor?

Comment: @codingFun Read a C++ book; you obviously don't understand how C++ works. In your example, you don't need to do anything to free the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) a `std::string` and free the memory associated with it, you can clear the string using `b.clear()` and then request that its storage be [shrunk to fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) with `b.shrink_to_fit()`.

Taking your example, you'd write:

```
struct strDum {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    strDum(): a(), b() {};
};

//in the code
strDum x;
x.b.append("this is a long string ....");
//do something else
...
x.b.clear();
x.b.shrink_to_fit();
```

Note that the call to `shrink_to_fit()` is non-binding; that is, the system is free to ignore it. Even if the memory is deallocated from the string (making it available to subsequent allocations within your program), you may find that the virtual memory usage ("vsize") of your process does not decrease. Reclaiming freed memory in this way is dependent on the library implementation and on the operating system itself.

Note also that you need not free this memory unless the string persists for a long time. If the string goes out of scope, its destructor will clean up for you. You'd only need to use this clear/shrink_to_fit method if you want to reuse the string (with content of significantly different size) or if your string object persists long enough that the memory it uses is needed elsewhere, but the content of the string is no longer required.